# Do i need a dependency injection container here

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I have the following dependencies that need set up at that start of my program:

```
//Set up dependencies
$fileSettings  = array(12, 'extra_lines', 'close_on_save');
$exporter      = new Exporter('exporterpath/filename.txt', $fileSettings);
$outputStream  = new OutputStream();
$businessModel = new BusinessModel('param1', 'param2');

//Run application
$application   = new Application($exporter, $outputStream, $businessModel);
$application->start();
```

So here you can see i have a few dependencies for my main application, and this is the code needed at bootstrap in order to inject everything required.

Does this warrant a dependency injection container?

If not, would a factory method be more suitable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good dependency injection article (PHP even!).

http://fabien.potencier.org/article/12/do-you-need-a-dependency-injection-container

From the article:

> Most of the time, you don't need a Dependency Injection Container to
>   benefit from Dependency Injection.
>
> But when you need to manage a lot of different objects with a lot of
>   dependencies, a Dependency Injection Container can be really helpful
>   (think of a framework for instance).

I believe the correct answer has to do with how complex your scenario is. At some point, something, somewhere, has to know how to put all of this together. If it's getting tedious and ugly, then it may be time for a container.

Actually, you never actually **have** to have a container. It's simply usually a good idea because of the flexibility it provides.

Comment: So in my example, based on the objects i have shown, do you think a di container would be required?  I didnt like that article as it seemed like more of a factory pattern.  But i am just learning so i am obviously mistaken.

Comment: Required? No. Good idea for flexibility and maintainability later? Yes.

Comment: IMO, in your case, it's perfectly acceptable to leave things the way they are. If that's all there is to it, leave it. But the next time you need to add to the complexity, consider a container at that time.

Comment: thanks as the last thing i would want to do is make things more complicated for the sake of it.  I think over engineering something can actually make it look like you dont know what you are doing